# Window vs WindowEx in WinUI-3

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I'm new to `WinUi-3` and I'm trying to do things in best practice way.
I have created an `Blank App` which creates a `MainWindow` of type `Window` from `Microsoft.UI.Xaml`.
As my **Boss** asked me to check `Template Studio For WinUI` I have tried to created a `Full-Feature` project using this `Template-Studio` wizard.

[image]

After that I saw a lots of extra files which were responsible for doing `WinUI` stuffs. One of these files was `MainWindow` which was inherited from `WindowEx` defined in `WinUIEx` library.

In my short experience of `WinUI` I saw many stability issues on this `Framework` and I'm really afraid of using new things there.

I don't really know that it will be helpfull or not.

Comment: [WinUI3Ex](https://github.com/dotMorten/WinUIEx#:~:text=A%20set%20of%20extension%20methods%20and%20classes%20to%20fill%20some%20gaps%20in%20WinUI%203%2C%20mostly%20around%20windowing%20and%20unit%20testing.) is not a framework. It just helps you implement some WinUI 3 features that are hard to use at the moment. I'd say you should try it especially if you are new to WinUI 3.

Answer (score 1):

[Install tools for the Windows App SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/set-up-your-development-environment?tabs=cs-vs-community%2Ccpp-vs-community%2Cvs-2022-17-1-a%2Cvs-2022-17-1-b) document lists the minimum required tools and workloads. It's recommended to glance through [Create your first WinUI 3 (Windows App SDK) project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/create-your-first-winui3-app) and [Using TS to build WinUI 3 apps](https://github.com/microsoft/TemplateStudio#documentation).